# How to write in excel file?

Tags: java, file, apache-poi

Java Class

```
       public void CandidateUpload(String path) {
      try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(path));

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        int c = 1;

        while (c < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()) {
            Row row1 = sheet.getRow(c);

            String firstname = row1.getCell(5).toString().trim();
            String lastname = row1.getCell(6).toString().trim();

           System.out.println("%%**---**" + firstname);
            System.out.println("%%**----**" + lastname);

            Cell name = row1.createCell(12);
            name.setCellValue("gokul");

            // sheet.getRow(12).getCell(11).setCellValue("gokul");

            c++;
           }
          } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
         }}


     error:28-Dec-2015 20:34:01.914 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-67]                       .opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn Content-Type not allowed: file "300634.xlsx" "upload_76a722f4_151e90da166__7fff_00000002.tmp" application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

WARNING *********** NetBeans HTTP Monitor ************
The request cannot be recorded most likely because the NetBeans HTTP Monitor module is disabled.

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: resourceEntries

Comment: Can you please explain what problem you are facing with more details?

Comment: how to insert value in excel sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing the call to write

> workbook.write(java.io.OutputStream stream)

From the How To Guide:

> Once you have generated your workbook, you can write it out by calling write(outputStream) from your instance of Workbook, passing it an OutputStream (for instance, a FileOutputStream or ServletOutputStream). You must close the OutputStream yourself. HSSF does not close it for you.

check out the [POI Quick Guide](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook) and the [How To Guide](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html)